# Centos 7 cannot find with fdisk

Tags: centos7, mount, fdisk

I can find  */dev/vda1* with `fdisk` but */dev/vdb* does not be found.
What happened? And how I can resolve it?

Thanks

```
[root@tp-gpdb-ku05 master]# fdisk -l                           

Disk /dev/vda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                         
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes          
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes              
Disk label type: dos                                           
Disk identifier: 0x000b1ef9                                    

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/vda1   *        2048   209715166   104856559+  83  Linux  

Disk /dev/vdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                         
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes          
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes              

[root@tp master]# fdisk -l /dev/vdb

Disk /dev/vdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

[root@tp master]#
[root@tp master]#df
/dev/vda1      104846316 5513836  99332480   6% /
devtmpfs         3984412       0   3984412   0% /dev
tmpfs            4005084   16768   3988316   1% /run
tmpfs            4005084       0   4005084   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb       104806400  156308 104650092   1% /data
```

Comment: Subject is contradicted by content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that /dev/vdb is found, available and in use, mounted as /data.

```
/dev/vdb       104806400  156308 104650092   1% /data
```

Comment: But I expect like
Device        Boot        Start     End         Blocks      Id    System 
/dev/vda1      *          2048      1026047     512000      83    Linux
/dev/vdb                 1026048   1640447     307200      8e    Linux LVM
when I type fdisk -l , but /dev/vdb disappear

Comment: It hasn't disappeared, it is demonstrably there. The whole disk is in use rather than being partitioned like /dev/vda is.

Comment: I see.  But if it is not problem, why mount cannot work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990108/centos7-mount-a-mount-o-remount-doesnt-work

Comment: I don't see any evidence of mount failing.

Comment: Even use "mount -a"  the parameters of  disk of /etc/fstab are not the same with current mounted disks